# Set IE compatibility mode using X-UA-Compatible

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility-mode

We have noticed that in some IE8 and IE9 and IE10 the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Emulate IE7" />
```

is not respected...or at least looks like the browser ignores it.

Any other suggestons how to explicitly set the compatibility mode in IE?

We use some thirt parthy (rish faces3) components in our software that does not work in IE8+ and upgrading those is not an option.

Comment: Are you running your content in an iframe? Iframes run in the same mode as their parent page.

Comment: No no Iframe ... it was working ok until a few days ago that some customers for our webap started to complain ... mybe there was some IE update that affect this ... this is only a guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper value is `IE=EmulateIE7` with no space in it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the following meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

This will display the site as if it's IE7, rather than emulating IE7

Comment: That's a bit misleading. "IE=7" means "Render this document in IE7 Standards mode." "EmulateIE7" means "Render this document in IE7 standards mode unless it's a quirks-mode document in which case you should render it in Quirks mode."